# Need help picking components for a stir plate

Tags: dimmer

I  was going to make a stir plate to grow yeast for brewing beer. It involves using some type of housing (cigar box, wooden box), wiring some DC voltage to a switch, to a dimmer controller, to a PC fan inside the box. On the center of the fan, you glue magnets. When the magnets rotate, that rotates a magnetic bar inside your flask of yeast that is sitting on top of the box. It is a pretty common DIY project.

My trouble is, I'm not sure what I should be using here. I was planning on getting a 12 volt DC adapter and wiring that to a simple toggle switch.  But, I'd also like to add a DC speed control to the motor.  Can someone provide me guidance to get me started down that path?